# multiple forms on page onclick ajax function not working

Tags: php, ajax

I have an ajax search function that produces a list of names from database. Each name is echoed back as a form button so when user clicks on the name another ajax call will bring up all info related to that name. However, it is not working. I have tried several variations of the ajax function below but either nothing happens at all or the page just gets refreshed with no results.
Any ideas on how to get this to work?

This is the latest ajax (which does nothing)

```
$(function GetInfo() {
    $('form').on('click', function (e) {
    var tourName = $('#tourName').val();
    var FirstName = $('#FirstName').val();
    var LastName = $('#LastName').val();
alert("PLEASE ENTER A NAME" + FirstName + LastName);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'process.php',
            data: "tourName=" + tourName + "&firstname=" + firstname + "&lastname=" + lastname,
     success: function(data){
    $("#search_results").html(data);
        }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    });
```

And this is the php loop that produces the forms (names):

```
$string = '';

if (mysql_num_rows($query)){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
$FirstName = $row['FirstName'];
$LastName = $row['LastName'];
$Name = $row['FirstName']." ".$row['LastName'];
$string .= "<form method='post' action=''>
<input type='hidden' name='FirstName' value='$FirstName'>
<input type='hidden' name='LastName' value='$LastName'>
<input type='button' class='button' name='person_name' value='$Name' onClick='GetInfo()'></form><br /><br />\n";
}

}else{
$string = "No matches found!";
}
    mysql_close($con);
echo $string;
```

Just incase anyone has the same issue, I got the following code to work:

```
   function GetInfo(form) {
    var person_name = form.person_name.value;
    var tourName = form.tourName.value;
    var firstname = form.FName.value;
    var lastname = form.LName.value;
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "process.php",
          data: "person_name=" + person_name + "&tourName=" + tourName + "&firstname=" +    firstname + "&lastname=" + lastname,
          success: function(data){
        $("#search_results").html(data);
        }
       });
        return false;
          }
```

And in the form

```
$string .= "<form method='post' id='$form'>
<input type='hidden' name='tourName' value='$tourneyName'>
<input type='hidden' name='FName' value='$FirstName'>
<input type='hidden' name='LName' value='$LastName'>
<input type='button' class='button' name='person_name' value='$Name' onClick='GetInfo   (this.form)'></form><br /><br />\n";
}

}else{
$string = "No matches found!";
}
```

Comment: Use `submit` instead of `click`.

Comment: @JJPA  I have tried that and the page just gets refreshed

Comment: Numerous issues:
Your jquery selectors are looking for items with id="tourName" etc, whilst none of your form fields have ids set.
If the ids where set, you would have duplicate ids and it would still fail.

You are using onclick to call a jquery function that is wrapping an event listener
probably a bunch of other problems

Comment: Suggest reading up on jquery

Comment: I tried function GetInfo(){

     var firstname = form.find('input[name=FirstName]').val();
     var lastname = form.find('textarea[name=LastName]').val();
  alert("working" + firstname + lastname);
     $("#search_results").show();
   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "tourney_users_add_ent.php",
        data: "firstname=" + firstname + "&lastname=" + lastname,
        success: function(data){
   $("#display_results").html(data);
   }
     });
   return false;
        }    This will alert with undefined variables. not sure how to get id's in to the mix as you said

Comment: You don't have `textarea`s in your form, you have `input`s. And you haven't set the variable `form`, it should be `$(this)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$(function GetInfo(el) {
    var tourName = $('#tourName').val();
    var FirstName = $(el).siblings('[name=FirstName]').val();
    var LastName = $(el).siblings('[name=LasstName]').val();
    alert("PLEASE ENTER A NAME" + FirstName + LastName);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'process.php',
        data: { tourName: tourName, firstname: FirstName, lastname: LastName },
        success: function(data){
            $("#search_results").html(data);
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

And you need to change the HTML to use:

```
onclick='GetInfo(this)'
```

Comment: It does nothing. same as what I had.

Comment: I see the problem. `GetInfo()` isn't doing the AJAX submit, it's just binding a click handler.

Answer (score 0):

You should add an ID to you form and target instead of using $('form') use $('#yourformid')

Comment: There could be 50+ forms on page

Answer (score 0):

The solution is posted above. It seems rather simple now that it's done.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#send_email').click(function() {    
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url  : '<?php echo base_url()?>contact',
        data : $( '#contact_form' ).serialize(),         
        success : function(msg){
        $('#results').html(msg);
        if(msg == "Successfully Subscribed"){
            $( "#email_news" ).val('');
         }

        } 

    });
return false;
});
```